# Create datagridview with combobox in the second column

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a datagridview with a combobox in the second column.

Currently my datagrid is bound to a datatable. The field patient is what I need to have in the combobox.

The code below adds the field but it is at the end of the grid and is duplicated...i.e there are 2 patient fields.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataColumn dtColumn;

dtColumn = new DataColumn("ClmDate", typeof(String));
dt.Columns.Add(dtColumn);

dtColumn = new DataColumn("Patient", typeof(Decimal));
dt.Columns.Add(dtColumn);

dtColumn = new DataColumn("ClmAmt", typeof(Decimal));
dt.Columns.Add(dtColumn);

cService cservice = new cService();

var trans = cservice.ClmView(txtNo.Text.Trim());

if (trans != null)
{
    // Add items to datatable
    foreach (var t in trans)
    {
        //save to datatable
        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        row["clmdate"] = t.clmdate.ToShortDateString();
        row["patient"] = t.patient;
        row["clmAmt"] = t.clmamt;

        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    } 
}

Grid_Refresh();

private void Grid_Refresh()
{
    grdTrans.DataSource = dt;    

    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    cb.HeaderText = "Patient";
    cb.Name = "Patient";
    cb.Items.Add("Foo");
    cb.Items.Add("Bar");
    grdTrans.Columns.Add(cb);        
}
```

Below would be an image of the grid I am trying to reproduce...

http://s13.postimage.org/aale668uf/grd.png

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not that it should impact the problem, but storing a date as a string has a fair likelyhood of biting you at some point.

"dtColumn = new DataColumn("ClmDate", typeof(String));"

Comment: Will have a look into that. Was just really giving a small sample of the code. The grid is bigger than this and includes a button as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the patient column twice. Once to the data:

```
dtColumn = new DataColumn("Patient", typeof(Decimal));
dt.Columns.Add(dtColumn);
```

And once explicitly in `Grid_Refresh()`:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
cb.HeaderText = "Patient";
cb.Name = "Patient";
cb.Items.Add("Foo");
cb.Items.Add("Bar");
grdTrans.Columns.Add(cb);
```

I think you need to set [`DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx)`= false`, and manually create all of the columns.

Comment: Or remove the "Patient" column from the DataGridView and then add it back as a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

Comment: Hopefully my answer helped you then. If it did, you should consider accepting it.